# Cloudbuild failing on flask app due to incopatibility of functions-framework and Flask

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to build my code using CloudBuild, but it's failing with the following message:

`Error: Error while updating cloudfunction configuration: Error waiting for Updating CloudFunctions Function: Error code 3, message: Build failed: found incompatible dependencies: "functions-framework 3.0.0 has requirement flask<3.0,>=1.0, but you have flask 3.0.0."; Error ID: 5503c41a │`

I've checked my dependencies and subdependencies, and I've tried to release the same code that was releasable 2 weeks ago, and I'm getting this error everywhere. I'm not using Flask 3.0.0 anywhere, my version is 2.3.3.

My guess is that this is some temporary problem, since I haven't found anything online, and google has already had problems with functions-framework before, but I'm interested if someone has found a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by setting fixed (latest) version of `functions-framework`, which is `3.4.0` at the time of writing this comment in my `requirements.txt`.

Why GCP doesn't use latest version of their own libary is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `functions-framework>=3.4.0` didn't work for me:

```
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of functions-framework to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could
take a while.

ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 2) and flask==3.0.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
  The user requested flask==3.0.0
  functions-framework 3.4.0 depends on flask<3.0 and >=1.0
```

I didn't specify flask=3.0.0 but that's the current version.

Setting `flask=2.3.3` without specifying a function-framework version worked.

Comment: My flask is set to `2.3.3` as well.